# Flash security dialog box

Tags: flash, apache-flex, flex4

I'm trying to modify Flex app using Flex SDK 4.1 The problem is security dialog box in which user can allow access to microphone does not appears on: `var mic:Microphone = Microphone.getMicrophone();`. I can easily show advanced dialog box with `Security.showSettings(SecurityPanel.PRIVACY);`, but I want to use default dialog with buttons.

Comment: Check the size of the application at the time security dialog should be displayed. Flash has size limitations when doing with security. Size must be at least 215 x 138 pixels for security dialog to appear.

Comment: I don't think OP's problem is caused by the size of the app, as he says he is showing the privacy panel w/out issue. If I recall correctly, OP, you might have to do more than just get the microphone (I'm assuming your code actually tries to use it -- but who knows).

Answer (score 0):

If first time you canceled access to the microphone and want get microphone second time, security popup not will open. Use as like:

```
private var _mic:Microphone;

protected function initMicrophone():void 
{               
    _mic = Microphone.getMicrophone();

    if (_mic == null) return;

    if (_mic.muted)
    {
        Security.showSettings(SecurityPanel.PRIVACY);
    }
}
```